# Resolving a vector into components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

Scenario 1:
There is a block on a horizontal table on which I'm applying a force of 10N. 
Scenario 2:
Block B has mass m and block A has mass 3m. Tension in cord CD while B is sliding down A is $\frac{mg}2$sin$2\theta$.

[image: image of block silding down a wedge]

In the first scenario, the vertical component of the force is zero because cos$\frac{π}2$ is zero. But we can also choose an arbitrary angle $\theta$ (between the horizontal and the vertical),take the component of that force along said angle, and once again resolve that component by $\frac{π}2-\theta$ along vertical axis to get a component of force along the vertical. I was told that this is not possible. 
 In the second scenario however, we do take the component of an already resolved vector again to get the tension. What is so special in the second case that we can't do the same for the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was told that this is not possible.

It is possible, it is just not useful.

> What is so special in the second case that we can't do the same for the first one?

Nothing. You can do it, it just is not useful to do so.

So, in the first case, you can certainly split your original horizontal force into components with respect to an angled basis. You can always do that, it is just math.

Let’s say your horizontal basis vector is $\hat i$ and your vertical basis vector is $\hat j$. Now, you can write any vector in terms of the $(\hat i, \hat j)$ basis. But you can also consider a basis rotated by $\theta$, which we will call the $(\hat k,\hat l)$ basis. The transform is: $$\hat i = \cos(\theta) \hat k - \sin(\theta) \hat l$$$$\hat j=\sin(\theta) \hat k+ \cos(\theta)\hat l$$

Now, if you start with a purely horizontal vector then we can write $\vec F = F \hat i$. If we switch to the rotated basis then $$\vec F = F \cos(\theta) \hat k - F \sin (\theta) \hat l$$

Now if you want to find the vertical component you simply take the dot product with $\hat j$, the unit vector in the vertical direction: $$\vec F \cdot \hat j =  F \cos(\theta) \hat k \cdot \hat j- F \sin (\theta) \hat l \cdot \hat j$$$$\vec F \cdot \hat j =  F \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) - F \sin (\theta) \cos(\theta)$$$$\vec F \cdot \hat j =  0$$

So changing to a different basis does not suddenly make your horizontal vector have any vertical component. $\vec F$ has components in both the $\hat k$ and $\hat l$ directions, but not in the $\hat j$ direction.

Comment: So to speak, I could still say the vertical component of my 10N force on aforementioned block is, say, 5N. But you just proved it should be zero. Why does it not give the answer out as zero in that case, then?

Comment: @StudiousElectron $\vec F$ has no component in the $\hat j$ direction. $\vec F$ does have a component in the $\hat k$ direction and $\hat k$ has a component in the $\hat j$ direction. But that does not mean that $\vec F$ has a component in the $\hat j$ direction.